# How to add Authorization Header to client handshake request in Eclipse-jetty-websocket version-8

Tags: jetty, basic-authentication, end-of-life

I want to add Authorization header for basic Authorization to my jetty-client request.

I am running two instances on same browser one is server one is client ,Java-8 is being used as a technology, No DB No Spring etc. using  org.eclipse.jetty,jetty-websocket,version-8.1.15.v20140411.

I had a websocketEndPointManager class which contains the initialization  method for both Server(dedicated class is CSWebsocket)  and client(Cpwebsocket).

How can I achieve basic auth in my scenario where server maintains username and password is to matched in current session after its instance is ready, currently my setup able to perform upgrade to websocket but not basic

Snippet of client websocket start method where handshake occur :

```java
  private void startCPWebSocket() throws Exception{
                 String uri ="";
           try {
            HandlerRegistry.register(this);
WebSocketClientFactory factory = new  WebSocketClientFactory();

Configuration configuration = TestSession.getConfiguration();
    uri = configuration.getSystemUnderTestEndpoint();
TestSession.getConfiguration().setToolURL("NA");
TestSession.getConfiguration().setSystemUnderTestEndpoint(uri);
factory.start();

WebSocketClient client = factory.newWebSocketClient();
client.setMaxIdleTime(24*60*60*1000);


client.open(new URI(uri.trim()),new CPWebSocket()).get(24*60*60,
                                       TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    LogUtils.logInfo("WebSocket URL : "+uri,true);
   }
            catch (ExecutionException e) {
  LogUtils.logError(e.getMessage(), e,false);
LogUtils.logWarn("Could not establish websocket connection.",true);
            //System.exit(0); 
            TestSession.setTerminated(true);
            throw e;
```

Comment: [Jetty 8 websocket was deprecated and declared EOL (End of Life) years ago](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html).  It no longer supports the current WebSocket protocol standard properly (it will fail with various mobile networks, various ISPs, many backend websocket servers, etc).   Please consider upgrading.

Comment: Can we achieve the goal using custom headers .Javax websocket configurator is supported by jetty8 ?

Comment: The first stable release of javax.websocket support was in Jetty 9.2.0